# Matplotlib Gridspec "Cell" labels

Tags: python, matplotlib

Using [GridSpec](http://matplotlib.org/users/gridspec.html), I have a regular lattice of plots.  Assume 3 x 3.  All plot axis are turned off as I am interested in the shape of the plot, not the individual axis values.

What I would like to do, is label the x and y axis of the larger box.  For example, in the 3 x 3 case above, the x-axis could be ['A', 'B', 'C'] and the y-axis could be [1,2,3].

Is it possible to get this labeling?  How can I access the grid spec axis?

Not much in the [GridSpec documentation](http://matplotlib.org/1.3.1/api/gridspec_api.html) unless I am missing an obvious method name.

Code example.  Data is in a pandas dataframe - ignore the brute force extraction with nested loops...

```
    fig = plt.figure(figsize=(12,12))

    gs = gridspec.GridSpec(40, 19, wspace=0.0, hspace=0.0)

    for j in nseasons:
        t = tt[j]
        nlats = t.columns.levels[0]
        for idx, k in enumerate(nlats):
            diurnal = t[k].iloc[0]
            ax = plt.subplot(gs[j, idx])
            ax.plot(y, diurnal.values, 'b-')
            ax.set_xticks([])
            ax.set_yticks([])
            fig.add_subplot(ax)
            sys.stdout.write("Processed plot {}/{}\r".format(cplots, nplots))
            sys.stdout.flush()
            cplots += 1

    #Here the figures axis labels need to be set.
```

Comment: you can probably just add text the figure object itself, regardless if there's a GridSpec attached to it.

Comment: Maybe xlabel('A'), ylabel('1') etc?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, you can do this with xlabel and ylabel by only labeling axes on the left and bottom of the figure. Example below.

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.gridspec as gridspec

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(12,12))

rows = 40
cols = 19
gs = gridspec.GridSpec(rows, cols, wspace=0.0, hspace=0.0)

for i in range(rows):
    for j in range(cols):
        ax = plt.subplot(gs[i, j])
        ax.set_xticks([])
        ax.set_yticks([])

    # label y 
    if ax.is_first_col():
        ax.set_ylabel(i, fontsize = 9)

    # label x 
    if ax.is_last_row():
        ax.set_xlabel(j, fontsize = 9)

plt.show()
```

[image]